# Android intent-filter not filtering pathPrefix

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

We have lots of activities, but two were designed to start optionally from a URL using intent-filter.  These two activities have the same scheme and host, but they have different pathPrefix.  When we used a URL that matched one of these, it would just show our app once along with any browsers.  Now, it is showing our app for any URL that matches the scheme.  What we most care about is that its showing our app twice in our supported testing scenarios.

Does anyone have a workaround or know that this is a bug since we used to get the desired behavior?  Does someone know what we changed that broke this (we have switched API level, build tools version, etc).

```
     <activity
         android:name="com.ConfigurationLoadingActivity"
         android:label="@string/title_activity_configuration_loading" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
         android:noHistory="true" >
         <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/app_intent_filter_host" android:pathPrefix="/mobilecloud/configuration" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>




     <activity
         android:name="com.SchoolSelectionActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
         android:label="@string/title_activity_school_selection"
         android:noHistory="true" >

        <intent-filter android:label="@string/configuration_list">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/app_intent_filter_host" android:pathPrefix="/mobilecloud/cloud" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you only have one instance of your app installed? You are using a string resource for the host, suggesting that perhaps you are using stuff like `debug` and `release` build types. If you have both `debug` and `release` installed, and there's a bug where both have the same value for the `app_intent_filter_host` string resource, that would explain the behavior.

Comment: Checked that I currently only have the app installed once.  I tried different URLs used in the data of the intent I send from a second app, and the original app will respond to anything that starts with https, the host value.  We haven't changed this code or the manifest structure, so I believe it might be related to changing the API version or build tools or something along those lines.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but did you find a solution? I'm also stuck with the same problem and google sent me here :)

Comment: No sorry, I am no longer associated with the product that caused it.